# phpのコードについて質問します。

Tags: php

以下のような関数があるのですが、この中のコードに関して２点質問します。

1.「 ORDER BY `order`");」とはどういう意味ですか？

2.「while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $product["sizes"][] = $row["size"];
    }」はどういう意味ですか？

---

```
function get_product_single($sku){
    require(ROOT_PATH. "inc/database.php");
    try{
        $results=$db->prepare("SELECT name, price, img, sku,paypal FROM products where sku=?");
        $results->bindParam(1,$sku);
        $results->execute();
    }catch (Exception $e){
      echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
      exit;
    }

    $product=$results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($product===false)return $product;
    $product["sizes"]=array();
    try{
        $results=$db->prepare("
        SELECT size
        FROM products_sizes ps 
        INNER JOIN sizes s ON ps.size_id=s.id
        WHERE product_sku=?
        ORDER BY `order`");
        $results->bindParam(1,$sku);
        $results->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
        exit;
    }
    while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $product["sizes"][] = $row["size"];
    }

    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

利用されているのはMySQLですよね？

1. カラム order でソートするという意味です。
   order はMySQLの予約語ですので、SQL中でカラム名として使う場合は `（バッククオート）で囲む必要があります。
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/reserved-words.html
2. SQLの結果をすべて、配列 $product["sizes"] へ追加しています。
   $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) についてはマニュアルが参考になります。
   http://php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.fetch.php